# Comparison of Multiple column of single row in Informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a requirement in Informatica powercenter development, where I need to populate a column after multiple column Compaeisons

Like for ex - we have Brand name in 30 Columns of same row, I have to populate a field in target table based on all these 30 Columns, if all the 30 Brands are equal then only we have to populate the Brand name else I have to populate Brand do not match.

also there may be case that some brands fields are  are null but we do not have to compare that with not null Brands.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a `DECODE` function with `OR`, or do an `MD5` on concatenation of all your columns and compare the result.

Comment: Thanks!! the comparing part is what I am not getting , lik ehow can we compare  brand1=brand2=brand3----barnd30 and then populate the result.  all the brands is coming in same row.

Comment: How about: brand1=brand2 AND brand2=brand3 AND...?